# Generate row table from this customised static row

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have some trouble tring to achieve the creation of one row from JS in my table. I do not know why?

[image]

My static row:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    Bob
  </td>
  <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The second code is when generated in my add function:

```
let row = "<tr>"
    + "<td>"
       + "<a href='#'>"+ person.name +"</a>"
    + "</td>"
    + "<td class='text-right text-nowrap'>"
       +  "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-info'>edit</button>"
       +  "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'>"
          +  "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>"
       +  "</button>"
    +  "</td>"
    +  "</tr>"
```

Comment: This post may help, please [Check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615850/bootstrap-adding-rows-to-a-table)

Comment: What tableRows variable contains??? I mean it's a table instance or tbody instance???

Comment: I remove it, it belongs to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no div around table rows. How are you accessing the table from Javascript. See the following snippet.

I have added

```
<div id = "table">
```

and used the

```
JQuery on ready function,
```

to wait till the page loads,
and append the row to the proper table "div" using append function.

```js
var row = "<tr>" +
    "<td>"
       + "<a href='#'> Aadi </a>"
    + "</td>"
    + "<td class='text-right text-nowrap'>"
       +  "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-info'>edit</button>"
       +  "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'>"
          +  "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>"
       +  "</button>"
    +  "</td>" + "</tr>"


    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#table tbody').append(row);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='table'>

<table>
 <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    Bob
  </td>
  <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Good to hear that ... Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: is it ok if I put (id = "table") in my tbody

Comment: I think, keeping the id in <div> would be more cleaner. As tbody and table tags are mostly used to add other attributes like class and style.